# Prove Four Statements Are Equivalent

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I have the following problem, where $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices, prove the following statements are equivalent:
1.  $G$ is connected and acyclic
2.  $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges
3.  $G$ is acyclic and has $n-1$ edges
4.  $G$ is connected and every edge has a cut edge

I could walk through the list and prove that 1 is true iff 2 is true, etc.  but is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: You just need a hamilton cycle of the proofs :)

Comment: @Jeremy Actually you only need a strongly connected di-graph. Most of the times Hamiltonian cycles are fastest and simplest, but not always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have something that asks you to "prove the following are equivalent", you just need to prove each statement implies the others. To do this, you could show

$$1\implies2\implies3\implies4\implies1$$
or any combination that hits each of the statements and is a cycle (hence my comment). So you could also do
$$2\implies3\implies1\implies4\implies2$$

Just do whatever is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You have four statements: 1, 2, 3, 4 and you need to show they are all equivalent. There are lots of ways of doing this. One of the simplest is proving $1 \implies 2, 2 \implies 3, 3 \implies 4, 4 \implies 1$. This shows all the statements are equivalent because starting at any statement and following the implication arrows, you can get to every other statement.

If you let the statements be vertices and the implication arrows be directed edges, then all you need is to construct a graph with the property that starting at any vertex, you can travel to any other vertex.